# How to return Value based on Subquery in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a table with `ITEM , OPCODE ,WorkCenter, LOT , COIL ,Strt_Time(DateTime)` .I want to return Previous WorkCenter and NextWorkCenter along with `ITEM , OPCODE ,WorkCenter, LOT , COIL ,Strt_Time` .

A coil of particlular LOT will be routed from Workcenter to Workcenter with time stamp(`Strt_time`)

Please kindly advise how to achieve this in SQL Server 2008 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although I generally try to avoid using the non-standard top, here is the usual hack as a subquery: `(select top 1 WorkCenter from T t2 where t2.ITEM = t.ITEM and t2.Strt_Time < t.Strt_Time order by Strt_Time desc) as PrevWorkCenter` Reverse the compare and sort order for the next one.

Comment: Do next and prev have the same `ITEM`?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 you should use `LEAD` and `LAG` Functions.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, here is a workaround:

```
WITH WorkCenter_details AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY Strt_Time) rn,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY Strt_Time)) / 2 rndiv2,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY Strt_Time) + 1) / 2 rnplus1div2,
        ITEM, OPCODE, WorkCenter, LOT, COIL, Strt_Time
    FROM 
        MyTable
)
SELECT
    rn, rndiv2, rnplus1div2,
    ITEM, OPCODE, WorkCenter, LOT, COIL, Strt_Time,
    CASE 
       WHEN rn % 2 = 1 
          THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN WorkCenter END) OVER (PARTITION BY  rndiv2) 
          ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN WorkCenter END) OVER (PARTITION BY rnplus1div2)
    END AS WorkCenter_Previous,
    CASE 
       WHEN rn % 2 = 1 
          THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN WorkCenter END) OVER (PARTITION BY rnplus1div2) 
          ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN WorkCenter END) OVER (PARTITION BY rndiv2)
    END AS WorkCenter_Next
FROM 
    WorkCenter_details
ORDER BY 
    ITEM, Strt_Time
```

This works only if workcenter is numeric

Comment: Fadlallah, Thanks for the response. I tried this query but i have getting errors . It can't recognize column names from table . i changed "mytable" to "ALLPROD" actual table name

Comment: Fix it. Check it now